# fetch all row values with same user id in php?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on wordpress website and i just stuck over one sql query.

I need to get the values from database table which contain same user id.

here is my table:

[image]

And when i run select query in mysql it is fetching result correct:

[image]

But i dont know how to get this result in my php template.

this is my query i am using in php:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    $id=$current_user->ID;
    $skill1 =mysql_query("SELECT Skills FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id='{$id}' ");
```

I cant use get->result because it is showing error that get->result must contain object. Something like this error is.

This is what i am using after Mysql_query:

```
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($skill1);
  print_r($arr);
```

And the Output is: [image]

Wordpress code:

```
public static function init_fields() {
        if ( self::$fields )
            return;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    $user = $current_user->user_login;
    $useremail =  $current_user->user_email;
    $id=$current_user->ID;
$skill1 =mysql_query("SELECT ID,user_id,Skills FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id=$id"); 
$skill_note = mysql_fetch_array($skill1);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_candidate_details WHERE user_id='{$id}' LIMIT 1"); 
$expe_note = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$job_title = $expe_note['job-cat1'];
$user_loc = $expe_note['location_one_id'];
$row_num = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(Skills) FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id='{$id}' " );
$row_cnt = mysql_fetch_array($row_num);
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($skill1);
print_r($arr);
mysql_free_result($skill1);
    $skill_area = $skill_note['Skills'];
        self::$fields = apply_filters( 'submit_resume_form_fields', array(
            'resume_fields' => array(
                 'candidate_name' => array(
                    'label'       => __( 'Your name', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'required'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'Your full name', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                    'priority'    => 1,
                    'value'       => $user
                ),
                'candidate_email' => array(
                    'label'       => __( 'Your email', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'required'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'you@yourdomain.com', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                    'priority'    => 2,
                    'value'       => $useremail
                ),
                'candidate_title' => array(
                    'label'       => __( 'Professional title', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'required'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'e.g. "Web Developer"', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                    'priority'    => 3,
                    'value'       => $job_title
                ),
                'candidate_location' => array(
                    'label'       => __( 'Location', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'required'    => true,
                    'placeholder' => __( 'e.g. "London, UK", "New York", "Houston, TX"', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                    'priority'    => 4,
                    'value'       => $user_loc
                ),

            'resume_skills' => array(
                'label'       => __( 'Skills', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                'type'        => 'text',
                'required'    => false,
                'placeholder' => __( 'Comma separate a list of relevant skills', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                'priority'    => 9,
                'value'      =>  $skill_area

            ),
            'links' => array(
                'label'       => __( 'URL(s)', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                'type'        => 'links',
                'required'    => false,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'description' => __( 'Optionally provide links to any of your websites or social network profiles.', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                'priority'    => 10,
                'fields'      => array(
                    'name' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Name', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => '',
                        'priority'    => 1
                    ),
                    'url' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'URL', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => 'http://',
                        'priority'    => 2
                    )
                )
            ),
            'candidate_education' => array(
                'label'       => __( 'Education', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                'type'        => 'education',
                'required'    => false,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'priority'    => 11,
                'fields'      => array(
                    'location' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'School name', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    ),
                    'qualification' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Qualification(s)', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    ),
                    'date' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Start/end date', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    ),
                    'notes' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Notes', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'textarea',
                        'required'    => false,
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    )
                )
            ),
            'candidate_experience' => array(
                'label'       => __( 'Experience', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                'type'        => 'experience',
                'required'    => false,
                'placeholder' => '',
                'priority'    => 12,
                'fields'      => array(
                    'employer' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Employer', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    ),
                    'job_title' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Job Title', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    ),
                    'date' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Start/end date', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'text',
                        'required'    => true,
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    ),
                    'notes' => array(
                        'label'       => __( 'Notes', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                        'type'        => 'textarea',
                        'required'    => false,
                        'placeholder' => ''
                    )
                )
            ), 
            'resume_file' => array(
                'label'       => __( 'Resume file', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ),
                'type'        => 'file',
                'required'    => false,
                'description' => sprintf( __( 'Optionally upload your resume for employers to view. Max. file size: %s.', 'wp-job-manager-resumes' ), size_format( wp_max_upload_size() ) ),
                'priority'    => 13,
                'placeholder' => ''
            ),
        )
    ) );
    if ( ! get_option( 'resume_manager_enable_resume_upload' ) )
        unset( self::$fields['resume_fields']['resume_file'] );

    if ( ! get_option( 'resume_manager_enable_categories' ) || wp_count_terms( 'resume_category' ) == 0 )
        unset( self::$fields['resume_fields']['resume_category'] );

    if ( ! get_option( 'resume_manager_enable_skills' ) )
        unset( self::$fields['resume_fields']['resume_skills'] );
}
```

Help me out guys! Thanks

Comment: post code after `mysql_query` and below all

Comment: $arr = mysql_fetch_array($skill1);
print_r($arr);

Comment: This is my code i am using after mysql_query

Comment: `echo $id` and check whether data is loaded.

Comment: yes it is containing value

Comment: @JaswinderKaur where you wrote `get->result` ?

Comment: use `get_results("SELECT Skills FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id='{$id}' ")`

Comment: Please add full code in your query, so we can get something.

Comment: i cant use get_result it is not working on my template.

Comment: @JaswinderKaur What do you mean by template?

Comment: If i use: $skill1 =$wpdp->get_results("SELECT Skills FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id='{$id}' ");

Comment: it shows: Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object in /home10/sombizbl/public_html/www.jobseeker.co.ke/wp-content/plugins/wp-job-manager-resumes/includes/forms/class-wp-resume-manager-form-submit-resume.php on line 152

Comment: @JaswinderKaur Ok then tag "Wordpress" in your question so someone get that you are working on Wordpress. So now i'm getting use `global $wpdb;` then check.

Comment: This is a plugin template where i am fetching values from my custom table. I dont know why it is showing fatal error

Comment: @JaswinderKaur After adding `global $wpdb;`? then also getting the same error?

Comment: @JaswinderKaur Add you whole Wordpress code here inside Wordpress: label.

Comment: code is very long how can i post it in comment

Comment: @KaushaMehta i had edited by question and added code over there. I had removed global $wpdp from this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, `$skill1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,user_id,Skills FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id='$id'");

```
        $count = count($skill1);
        $array = array();
        foreach ($skill1 as $key => $value) {
            $sk = $value->Skills;
            $array[] = $sk;
        }

        $fixId =array();
        $fixId[0] ='';
        for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++)
        {
            $temp = $array[$i];
            $fixId[0] = $fixId[0].$temp.',';
        }
        $data = $fixId[0] ;
        $words = array_filter(preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $data));
        $temp = implode(', ', $words);`
```

It will fetch data as an array with comma inserted between two values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_results` like below:

```
<?php

    global $wpdb;   //important  

    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Skills FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id='$id' ");  

    foreach($result as $row)
    {    
        echo $row->Skills."<br>";    
    }
```

[Display mysql table data in a wp page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-mysql-table-data-in-a-wp-page)

Comment: I had used global $wpdp; but same fatal error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

$id=$current_user->ID;

$skill1 =mysql_query("SELECT Skills FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id='".$id."' ");

$arr = mysql_fetch_array($skill1);

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code like below:

```
public static function init_fields() {
        if ( self::$fields )
            return;

    global $wpdb;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
    $user = $current_user->user_login;
    $useremail =  $current_user->user_email;
    $id=$current_user->ID;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,user_id,Skills FROM wp_candidate_skills WHERE user_id=$id");

    print_r($result);
    die();
}
```